# How to install different versions of Python in Mac (OS X)

Tags: python, macos

I am used to install different versions of Python in Mac (OS X) using Homebrew, but unliking and linking new versions is breaking things every now and then. I would like to know if there is a nicer way to install different versions of Python without causing any trouble.